# What is a good, free, AJAX PHP solution for creating a grid with right-click functionality?

Tags: php, ajax, httpwebrequest

I'd like to construct a grid, preferably with pagination built in, and do GETs POSTs etc from a right click submenu and have the grid update. We were using Ext but we found it do be too bulky for our uses. Can anyone recommend another library that is easy to use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Flexigrid](http://ww12.flexigrid.info/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [webdesignbooth.com](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/flexigrid.jpg))</sub>

### [TableSorter](https://closed.loopia.com/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [webdesignbooth.com](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/tablesorter.jpg))</sub>

### [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [webdesignbooth.com](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/datatables.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One more...

SDTable ([downloads section with free version](http://www.sdtable.com/downloads))
Pros: Very easy to create and customize with a drag and drop GUI, customizable into every detail.
Cons: Somewhat lacking API documentation.

[image: SDTable demo]